# Django save Base64 image

Tags: python, django, base64

I am accepting a POST from iOS and my django code is

```
        image =self.request.DATA.get('image')
        image_data =base64.b64decode(image)
        img=ContentFile(image_data,'myImage.jpg')
```

but when i save it in django it is currupted any ideas why

Here is my base64image

```
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 Ci5/f2lt/9yu3 Y8v2cMpb1/DSJbz5i9R2NLwfLrWbw m T8I8////////SvMAbAAAABB0Uk5T////////////////////AOAjXRkAAACYSURBVHjaLI8JDgMgCAQ5BVG3//9t0XYTE2Y5BPq0IGpwtxtTP4G5IFNMnmEKuCopPKUN8VTNpEylNgmCxjZa2c1kafpHSvMkX6sWe7PTkwRX1dY7gdyMRHZdZ98CF6NZT2ecMVaL9tmzTtMYcwbP y3XeTgZkF5s1OSHwRzo1fkILgWC5R0X4BHYu7t/136wO71DbvwVYADUkQegpokSjwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Python 2.7
f = open("yourfile.png", "wb")
f.write(your_base_string.decode('base64'))
f.close()

# or
with open("yourfile.png", "wb") as f:
    fhfwrite(imgData.decode('base64'))
```